# Ruby 2 syntax, $ `

Tags: ruby

I've sound some chunk of code, and can not understand the syntax. And I can not make good search. The code is

```
keys.map { |k| k =~ /\./; $` }
```

What mean $`   ? I tried to play with it in console, but did not understood how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using regex to match a string, the $` matches the string before the current match. Like so:

```
irb> "hello world".match(/world/)
 => #<MatchData "world">
irb> $`
 => "hello "
```

I should add the Ruby doc for reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html

More info: If you use the ['english' library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html), the ` can be replaced with the word PREMATCH:

```
irb> "hello world".match(/world/)
 => #<MatchData "world">
irb> $`
 => "hello "
irb> $PREMATCH 
 => nil
irb> require 'english'
 => true
irb> $PREMATCH 
 => "hello "
irb>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i asked

Comment: The documentation for `Regexp` lists the [special global variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables) concerning regular expressions.

Comment: In your examples, you can also refer to it via [`MatchData#pre_match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/MatchData.html#method-i-pre_match)